# Extract only right most n letters from a string

Tags: c#, string, substring

How can I extract a `substring` which is composed of the rightmost six letters from another `string`?

Ex: my string is `"PER 343573"`. Now I want to extract only `"343573"`.

How can I do this?

Comment: You could use the source code for the VB.NET Right method. You'd need to convert to C# first: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#Microsoft.VisualBasic/Strings.vb#0dbb15fffce19341
Convert to C# using http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: but the VB code relies on the c# Substring function in strings.sc

Comment: This is not really a very good way to do it, but if you're in a pinch, you can add a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll, and use the Right method. It is not an extension method. You have to use it like this:
`string endOfString = Strings.Right(wholeString, 6);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get last 4 character from a string in c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413572/how-to-get-last-4-character-from-a-string-in-c)

Answer (score 176, accepted):

```
string SubString = MyString.Substring(MyString.Length-6);
```

Comment: This aproach does not work correctly if the string is not as long as the number of characters required.

Comment: Depending on what exactly the OP wants one might also throw regular expressions at this. If s?he only wants the number at the end of the string, that's definitely the most painless solution, especially when the number of digits may vary in some later software upgrade.

Comment: @Johannes Rössel - I'm a big fan of regular expressions (see my answers), but I'd never recomend them for a simple situation such as this. Any of the answers that use a function wrapper are better suited to code maintanance than a regular expression. An extension method (or standard function if .NET 2.0) is the best solution.

Comment: @Stevo3000 - having a solution that throws if the string is the wrong length is a valid solution.  Not the only solution, but still.

Comment: @James - to be just as pernickity, only the title mentioned "n letters".  The actual question posed asked for "the rightmost six letters"  :)

Comment: @ChrisRogers this is true... however, I think it's obvious that a general utility function is more useful than a strict "give me 6 chars" function.

Comment: The question I read was `How can I extract a substring which is composed of the rightmost six letters from another string? ... How can I do this?` From this I gather that the OP had problems with exactly this part - the substring extraction itself. My answer shows how to do this. If the OP has other requirements beyond that (which is likely, but not mentioned here), he/she can adapt this line into a larger solution as fits his/her needs.

Answer (score 73):

Write an extension method to express the `Right(n);` function. The function should deal with null or empty strings returning an empty string, strings shorter than the max length returning the original string and strings longer than the max length returning the max length of rightmost characters.

```
public static string Right(this string sValue, int iMaxLength)
{
  //Check if the value is valid
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sValue))
  {
    //Set valid empty string as string could be null
    sValue = string.Empty;
  }
  else if (sValue.Length > iMaxLength)
  {
    //Make the string no longer than the max length
    sValue = sValue.Substring(sValue.Length - iMaxLength, iMaxLength);
  }

  //Return the string
  return sValue;
}
```

Comment: Start index cannot be less than 0 either.

Comment: @James - It won't be as `sValue.Length > iMaxLength` before a substring is called!

Comment: Great answer, but it was a bit of a double-take to see Hungarian notation in C# code.

Comment: @JeradRose - I work in a project where the code base evolved from a VB3 application (most of this is VB.NET) so there are some remnants.

Comment: @Jalle, VB.NET has Left, Right and Mid as top-level functions, plus many other helpful things that are not part of C#. Not sure why, as many of them are decent functions.

Answer (score 43):

Probably nicer to use an extension method:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Right(this string str, int length)
    {
        return str.Substring(str.Length - length, length);
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
string myStr = "PER 343573";
string subStr = myStr.Right(6);
```

Comment: Then it would throw a NullReferenceException just like it would if you tried to use any method on a null string...

Comment: `str.Length - length` could be negative. Also the second parameter is optional. No need to pass the length.

Comment: @JMS10 it certainly could be but thats more the callers concern than mine. Also, yes fair point, you could use the override that just takes the single parameter here.

Comment: str?.Substring(str.Length - length, length);

Answer (score 27):

```
using System;

public static class DataTypeExtensions
{
    #region Methods

    public static string Left(this string str, int length)
    {
        str = (str ?? string.Empty);
        return str.Substring(0, Math.Min(length, str.Length));
    }

    public static string Right(this string str, int length)
    {
        str = (str ?? string.Empty);
        return (str.Length >= length)
            ? str.Substring(str.Length - length, length)
            : str;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Shouldn't error, returns nulls as empty string, returns trimmed or base values.  Use it like "testx".Left(4) or str.Right(12);

Answer (score 16):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28VS.80%29.aspx)

```
String mystr = "PER 343573";
String number = mystr.Substring(mystr.Length-6);
```

EDIT: too slow...

Answer (score 11):

if you are not sure of the length of your string, but you are sure of the words count (always 2 words in this case, like 'xxx yyyyyy') you'd better use split.

```
string Result = "PER 343573".Split(" ")[1];
```

this always returns the second word of your string.

Comment: Yea; let's just assume OP's text ALWAYS has white spaces; like in his _example_ :)

Comment: Hei Christian :) we all know more than a couple of lines of an answer. I just answered the question in brief, of course, there are a lot more things to consider in real code.

Answer (score 10):

Since you are using .NET, which all compiles to [MSIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language), just reference [Microsoft.VisualBasic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic(v=vs.110).aspx), and **use Microsoft's built-in [`Strings.Right` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.right(v=vs.110).aspx)**:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
...
string input = "PER 343573";
string output = Strings.Right(input, 6);
```

No need to create a custom extension method or other work. The result is achieved with one reference and one simple line of code.

As further info on this, using Visual Basic methods with C# has been documented [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32215891/2658159). I personally stumbled on it first when trying to parse a file, and found [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3508572/2658159) on using the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser` class to be extremely useful for parsing .csv files.

Comment: This approach was also detailed in another SO thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15255454/2658159

Comment: That's MENTAL! But as VB guy, it's nice to lord it over the CSharpers for once!

Answer (score 9):

This isn't exactly what you are asking for, but just looking at the example, it appears that you are looking for the numeric section of the string.

If this is always the case, then a good way to do it would be using a regular expression.

```
var regex= new Regex("\n+");
string numberString = regex.Match(page).Value;
```

Comment: -1 regular expressions are a little overkill for something like this, especially when there are already built in methods for doing it.

Comment: I'm not arguing for using this method if you really do only need the last 6, but if your goal is to extract a number (such as an id) that may change to 5 or 7 digits at some point in the future, this is a better way.

Comment: Old answer, but +1 to support use of regular expressions.  Especially since there are (still) no built-in methods in .NET's String implementation for doing this @James.  Otherwise, this question may not have ever existed.

Comment: @CrazyIvan1974 not sure why you've mentioned me in your comment

Answer (score 6):

Use this:

```
String text = "PER 343573";
String numbers = text;
if (text.Length > 6)
{
    numbers = text.Substring(text.Length - 6);
}
```

Comment: text?.Substring(text.Length - 6)

Answer (score 5):

Guessing at your requirements but the following regular expression will yield only on 6 alphanumerics before the end of the string and no match otherwise.

```
string result = Regex.Match("PER 343573", @"[a-zA-Z\d]{6}$").Value;
```

Comment: Does this solution not reasonably meet the vague requirements?  If not, please explain your down voting.

Answer (score 5):

Another solution that may not be mentioned

```
S.Substring(S.Length < 6 ? 0 : S.Length - 6)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var str = "PER 343573";
var right6 = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str) ? string.Empty 
             : str.Length < 6 ? str 
             : str.Substring(str.Length - 6); // "343573"
// alternative
var alt_right6 = new string(str.Reverse().Take(6).Reverse().ToArray()); // "343573"
```

this supports any number of character in the `str`. the alternative code not support `null` string. and, the first is faster and the second is more compact.

i prefer the second one if knowing the `str` containing short string. if it's long string the first one is more suitable.

e.g.

```
var str = "";
var right6 = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str) ? string.Empty 
             : str.Length < 6 ? str 
             : str.Substring(str.Length - 6); // ""
// alternative
var alt_right6 = new string(str.Reverse().Take(6).Reverse().ToArray()); // ""
```

or

```
var str = "123";
var right6 = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str) ? string.Empty 
             : str.Length < 6 ? str 
             : str.Substring(str.Length - 6); // "123"
// alternative
var alt_right6 = new string(str.Reverse().Take(6).Reverse().ToArray()); // "123"
```

Comment: I like that alternative. Verbose, but easy to understand and handles the string-too-short issue automagically.

Answer (score 4):

**Null Safe Methods :**

Strings shorter than the max length returning the original string

**String Right Extension Method**

```
public static string Right(this string input, int count) =>
    String.Join("", (input + "").ToCharArray().Reverse().Take(count).Reverse());
```

**String Left Extension Method**

```
public static string Left(this string input, int count) =>
    String.Join("", (input + "").ToCharArray().Take(count));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

`string mystr = "PER 343573";
int number = Convert.ToInt32(mystr.Replace("PER ",""));`

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution I use...
It checks that the input string's length isn't lower than the asked length. The solutions I see posted above don't take this into account unfortunately - which can lead to crashes.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the last x-<paramref name="amount"/> of characters from the given string.
    /// If the given string's length is smaller than the requested <see cref="amount"/> the full string is returned.
    /// If the given <paramref name="amount"/> is negative, an empty string will be returned.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="string">The string from which to extract the last x-<paramref name="amount"/> of characters.</param>
    /// <param name="amount">The amount of characters to return.</param>
    /// <returns>The last x-<paramref name="amount"/> of characters from the given string.</returns>
    public static string GetLast(this string @string, int amount)
    {
        if (@string == null) {
            return @string;
        }

        if (amount < 0) {
            return String.Empty;
        }

        if (amount >= @string.Length) {
            return @string;
        } else {
            return @string.Substring(@string.Length - amount);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the method I use: I like to keep things simple.

```
private string TakeLast(string input, int num)
{
    if (num > input.Length)
    {
        num = input.Length;
    }
    return input.Substring(input.Length - num);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//s - your string
//n - maximum number of right characters to take at the end of string
(new Regex("^.*?(.{1,n})$")).Replace(s,"$1")
```

Comment: Somebody flagged your post for deletion and [I saw it in a review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18802695). I think your post was incorrectly flagged. [Code-only answers are not low-quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358757/1364007). Does it attempt to answer the question? If not, flag. Is it technically incorrect? Downvote.

Comment: Code should be accompanied with a written explanation on how it fixes the issue in the OP.

Comment: Well, i thought written explanation in comments was sufficient, no?

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought:

```
public static string Right(this string @this, int length) {
    return @this.Substring(Math.Max(@this.Length - length, 0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without resorting to the bit converter and bit shifting (need to be sure of encoding)
this is fastest method I use as an extension method 'Right'.

```
string myString = "123456789123456789";

if (myString > 6)
{

        char[] cString = myString.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(myString);
        Array.Resize(ref myString, 6);
        Array.Reverse(myString);
        string val = new string(myString);
}
```

Comment: `Array.Reverse` takes an array, not a string, and `if (myString.length > 6)`. Syntax errors aside, why would this be the fastest method? Surely just using substring would be a better way, it wouldn't require all this copying of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I use the Min to prevent the negative situations and also handle null strings

```
// <summary>
    /// Returns a string containing a specified number of characters from the right side of a string.
    /// </summary>
    public static string Right(this string value, int length)
    {
        string result = value;
        if (value != null)
            result = value.Substring(0, Math.Min(value.Length, length));
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using Microsoft.visualBasic;

 public class test{
  public void main(){
   string randomString = "Random Word";
   print (Strings.right(randomString,4));
  }
 }
```

output is "Word"

Answer (score 0):

```cs
            //Last word of string :: -> sentence 
            var str  ="A random sentence";
            var lword = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf(' ') + 1);

            //Last 6 chars of string :: -> ntence
            var n = 6;
            var right = str.Length >n ? str.Substring(str.Length - n) : "";
```