# C# substring in the middle

Tags: c#, string, substring

I have the following data:

```
D:\toto\food\Cloture_49000ert1_10_01_2013.pdf
D:\toto\food\Cloture_856589_12_01_2013.pdf
D:\toto\food\Cloture_66rr5254_10_12_2012.pdf
```

How can I extract the date part? 
For example:

```
D:\toto\food\Cloture_49000ert1_10_01_2013.pdf --> 10_01_2013
D:\toto\food\Cloture_856589_12_01_2013.pdf --> 12_01_2013
D:\toto\food\Cloture_66rr5254_10_12_2012.pdf --> 10_12_2012
```

My idea is to use `LastIndexOf(".pdf")`  and then count 10 character backwards.

How can I solve this using substrings or another method?

Comment: By the way, `D:\toto\food\Cloture_49000ert1_10_01_2013.pdf` is not a valid string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use *[`Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6.aspx)* in this case.

> Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a
>   specified character position.

Try like this;

```
string s = "D:\\toto\\food\\Cloture_490001_10_01_2013.pdf";
string newstring = s.Substring(s.Length - 14, 10);
Console.WriteLine(newstring);
```

Here is a *[`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/uWaGhs)*.

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to find index of `.pdf`

```
path.Substring(path.Length - 14, 10)
```

Comment: I assume that all filenames end like `dateString.pdf`

Answer (score 3):

I'd do this with a Regex.

```
^[\w:\\]+cloture_(\d+)_([\d_]+).pdf$
```

Would match the date in the second group.

Answer (score 2):

If the filename is always in that format, you could do something crude like this:

```
string filename = @"D:\toto\food\Cloture_490001_10_01_2013.pdf";

string date = filename.Substring(filename.Length - 14, 10);
```

That will get a substring from `10_01_2013.pdf`, which is 14 characters long, but only take the first `10` characters, leaving you with `10_01_2013`.

If, however, the filename is in a different format and the date could appear anywhere within the name, you may want to consider something like Regular Expressions to be able to do a match for `##_##_####` and pull that out.

Answer (score 0):

try this approach:

```
string dateString = textString.Substring(textString.Length-14, 10);
```

see here as well: [Extract only right most n letters from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722334/c-extract-only-right-most-n-letters-from-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use LastIndexOf then

```
string str = @"D:\toto\food\Cloture_490001_10_01_2013.pdf";
string temp = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf(".pdf") - 10, 10);
```

And you can parse it like

```
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(temp, "MM_dd_yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    //valid 
}
else
{
    //invalid
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with your idea of using `LastIndexOf` ".pdf" and then count backwards. Or use the [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx) method to just get the name and then take the last 10 characters.

These methods will both keep working if the path to the filenames ever changes (which it probably will) and don't rely on magic numbers (other than the one that defines the length of the substring we are interested in) to find the right place in the string.

Comment: If you think about it, it's still relying on magic numbers / positioning. The `Substring` solution doesn't rely on the filenames being the same length, though.

Comment: @RudiVisser - Well only the magic number of the length of the substring required.

Comment: True, but it's the same like `Substring`, apart from we assume a 3-char extension too :)