# Removing a specific set of data from a link

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following link: `/ABCDEF/ABCDEF/ABC/8921/154535`

I need to insert only the last 6 numbers i.e. `154535` in a column in a table.

Comment: Which rdbms you use?

Comment: what have you done so far

Comment: I tried using PAT Index, but I never used it before, so everything is going upside down ;)

Comment: here your answer......

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722334/extract-only-right-most-n-letters-from-a-string      select substr('TN0001234567890345',-10) from dual;

Comment: From where this link comes? Do you use .net language? Linq?

Comment: Please always add the code you are using to your questions, so they are readable both for people who wish to answer, and for future readers who wish to learn. If you can do that here, even though the question is already answered, that would be great (the code you supplied in a comment to libisyne is helpful).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code:

```
Declare @s varchar(100) = '/ABCDEF/ABCDEF/ABC/8921/154535'
select REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@s),0,CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(@s))))
```

Comment: I can't hardcode the '/ABCDEF/ABCDEF/ABC/8921/154535'
I have several of these in a table, and I need to do a select from that table to retrieve all of these :S
When am doing this: Declare @s varchar(100) = (select DISTINCT landing_page from [dbo].[No_of_Views]), it's giving me an error- returned more than 1 query..

Comment: @Shaz - You should add such details in your question. if you need to get this from your table, use `select REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(landing_page),0,CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(landing_page)))) FROM [dbo].[No_of_Views]`

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
Declare @s varchar(100) = '/ABCDEF/ABCDEF/ABC/8921/154535'
select substring(@s, patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]', @s), len(@s))
```

Comment: The above is working perfectly... The problem is i have these data in a table, where there are many links like this. I tried below code but it's not working: 
Declare @s varchar(100) = (select DISTINCT landing_page from [dbo].[No_of_Views]) 
--'/ABCDEF/ABCDEF/ABC/8921/154535'
select substring(@s, patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]', @s), len(@s)) from [dbo].[No_of_Views]

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning multiple rows to a variable. So, you get error : `returned more than 1 query`

Try below simple solution:

```
select DISTINCT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@s),0,CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(@s)))) from [dbo].[No_of_Views]
```

And if you want to `insert` then:

```
INSERT INTO table_name --your table name
select DISTINCT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@s),0,CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(@s)))) from [dbo].[No_of_Views]
```

Comment: The length of this number is not only 6, there are places where it is 5, and 4 :S