# Microsoft Visual Basic in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#

What are the benefits of adding "Microsoft Visual Basic" as a reference in Visual Studio Environment using C#?

Answer (score 5):

There are some useful classes in the [Visual Basic namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

The classes were originally added to that namespace to ease transition from VB6 to VB.Net.  However, being .NET classes, they can be directly consumed from any .NET language.